# Where is Summarize Raster Within tool in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, summarizing

I am looking for a tool to calculate mean across multiple rasters. I am aware of cell statistics tool that can be used here. I am also aware that raster calculator can also be used here. But, in my research I came across "Summarize Raster Within: Summarize Raster Within— Raster Analysis Tools.

However, I cannot locate this tool in my version of ArcGIS Pro 2.4.3. The tool I could find were for polygons (summarize within), not for rasters.

The [Summarize Raster Within](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/raster-analysis/summarize-raster-within.htm) tool was refered to at GeoNet.

Comment: Cell statistics and calculator are not even close. You are talking about zonal statistics as pointed in geonet comment.

Comment: @FelixIP I made a mistake in my reference to GeoNet threat, now this is corrected in my question. IN fact cell statistics does allow you to calculate the mean of two or more tasters as does the calculator. I am not taking about calculating mean within a raster, I am talking about across different rasters.

Comment: Please always include links when you mention other pages at this or any site.

Answer (score 1):

The [Summarize Raster Within](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/raster-analysis/summarize-raster-within.htm) tool:

> Summarizes a raster based on areas (zones) defined by the first input layer.

Its [Licensing Information](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/raster-analysis/summarize-raster-within.htm#L_) indicates that to use this tool requires an ArcGIS Image Server license.

If you do not have that license, then that may be why you are unable to find and use that tool.

Comment: I do not have that license, and could not find that info earlier. Thanks.